# Fontawesome not loading for vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, icons

Below I've pasted my code to show dependencies according to the documentation, along with the imports in my main.js. Finally, I've tried a lot of different ways of using the icons in my Footer.vue component, but they don't show up. When inspecting the element in the browser, they show up as < !---->and I can't find a solution to this.

I have also tried removing the brackets around the import of FontAwesomeIcon without any luck. Does anyone know what might be going on here?

*package.json*

```json
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
"@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^2.0.6",
"bootstrap-icons": "^1.7.2",
"vue": "^2.6.11",
```

*main.js*

```js
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

library.add(fas);
library.add(far);
library.add(fab);

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store: store,
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

*Footer.vue*

```js
<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'phone']" />
<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'faPhone']" />
<font-awesome-icon icon="phone" />
```

Comment: I don't have a repo I can work with right now, but suggest trying removing brackets around fas, far, and fab. These are bundles that are exported from their respective packages. So if you want the entire library, `import fas from ...` ... but if you want just some icons, `import  { icon1, icon2 ... } from ...`

Comment: Hey, I've tried that aswell and it doesnt yield anything. I've also tried specific icons with and without brackets and it acts the same.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vite-fontawesome?file=src%2Fmain.js). Note the second usage in `Footer.vue` is incorrect, as the icon names have no prefix (i.e., `faPhone` should be `phone` like in the first example usage).

Comment: Yeah, I'm just at a loss of what I should try next as I feel like anything I do will stray from what the documentation says. I looked at your example below and don't really understand why it doesn't show. I get a warning now that I didn't get before so I guess there is some progress. The error in the console tells me 'Coult not find one or more icon(s)' when trying `<font-awesome-icon :icon="['far', 'phone']"></font-awesome-icon>`.

Comment: That's because [`@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons` does not include the phone icon](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/svgs/regular). That icon is only available in [`@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons`](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/svgs/solid).

Comment: Yeah, I tried all prefixes thinking that mightve been the problem. Using 'fas' as the prefix led to the same problem. I think there is an issue with me using a vue.config.js file instead of adding a router with paths to the project. Maybe it doesn't know that the Footer.vue exists and therefor they're not recognized.

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: Same problem. @DragonInTraining found a solution?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro
Only a semi one as I described further down as an answer. I imported them directly in the component instead the main JS and it did the trick. But then you'd have to import them for each component you decide to use them in. Not the biggest of issues, but still is one.

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json is good.
Your method of consuming icons in the footer is correct in the first instance:

```
<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'phone']" />
```

(I don't know if you made up those other two tags or whether you've seen them in the docs but I haven't seem icons loaded that way before - I don't believe it to be valid)

The issue is your imports of the icons.
Suggest importing only phone and adding icons as you use them rather than trying to import all icons.

```
import { faPhone } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
library.add(faPhone)
```

Because `fas, fab and fas` are objects containing icons, and `library.add()` wants one or more icons (individually), you are sending an object not an icon as the param. [The docs](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome) don't show this is possible, perhaps you have seen this example elsewhere?

If you want to import multiple styles of the same icon, you can do it like this:

```
import { faPhone as fasPhone } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faPhone as farPhone } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
library.add(
  fasPhone,
  farPhone
)
```

Comment: The OP's registration actually works fine (see [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vite-fontawesome?file=src%2Fmain.js)).

Comment: Individual imports of specific icons don't work either. The imports of `fab, fas, far` is something I picked up from fontAwesome itself and should in theory import all icons.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a semi-answer, I would rather have them globally so I can re-use them later on. But for now, it'll have to do. I use them locally in the Footer.vue file and they work as intended.

I did this by removing the imports from `main.js` and imported everything directly in `Footer.vue`.